Apply CATransform3D to CALayer and save result in UIGraphicsImageRendererContext
I have an 4x4 transformation matrix that is converted to CATransform3D. I need to apply it a UIImage and save as a new image in Documents folder. Any transformations that I can apply to cgcontext inside UIGraphicsImageRenderer image method work only with affine transformations that doesn't suit me.
For now I have stuck with following implementation
extension UIImage {

    func transformed(by transform: CATransform3D) -> UIImage {
        let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: self.size))
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: self)
        imageView.layer.transform = transform

        containerView.addSubview(imageView)

        let boundingBox = containerView.bounds.applyCATransform3D(transform)
        let newSize = boundingBox.size

        containerView.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: newSize)

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize)
        let image = renderer.image { context in
            containerView.drawHierarchy(in: containerView.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        }
        return image
    }
}


The method returns image inside white canvas (which equals to newSize), but it doesn't save imageView.layer transformations.
I also tried to use CGContext concatenate method, but it also only works with CGAffineTransform:
 let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: newSize)
 let image = renderer.image { context in
    let cgContext = context.cgContext
    cgContext.concatenate(CATransform3DGetAffineTransform(transform))
    self.draw(at: .zero)
}
return image

Are there any native methods provided by Apple to achieve this or I have to use some 3rd party library like OpenCV to implement this?

You are applying transform to the layer of the image view, but that has nothing whatever to do with the image. What are you expecting / hoping to happen here?

There is no way to apply CATransform3D to UIImage or CGImage or CIImage. So the idea was to put UIImage that should be transformed to UIImageView, apply 3d transform to it and save it's transformed content. And it actually works but only if it's affine tranform.

I also tried to use CGContext concatenate method, but it also only works with CGAffineTransform (check out updated question code)

do you really want to do 3D transformations on your image, or do you just have a CATransform3D that contains 2D transformations?
If you only need 2D transforms, you should be able to extract the 2D transform from the CATransform3D and apply that.
Otherwise, you'll need to use another approach, e.g. install your image into a CALayer, install your CATransform3D into the layer, then use CALayer drawInContext to render the layer into your target context.
